# Numerically solving a system of three nonlinear equations by predefining functions

Tags: equation-solving, functions, variable

I have three functions of three variables, `f1(x,y,z)`,`f2(x,y,z)`, and `f3(x,y,z)`, and I'm trying to solve them using `Nsolve`. Since in the original format, they are pretty long expressions, I first want to define them as `f1,f2,f3` and then plug them into `Nsolve`. In a minimal reproducible example, I do the following:

```
f1[_x, _y, _z] = x^2 + y + 4 + 5*z
f2[_x, _y, _z] = x*y + y^2 + z + 4
f3[_x, _y, _z] = x*y*z

NSolve[f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0, {x, y, z}]
```

But when I execute this, I get the same thing as an output:

```
NSolve[f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0, {x, y, z}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @zhk Thanks, I fixed it, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For a system you have to pass the argument as a list `NSolve[{},{}]`.
2. When defining a function, each argument should be followed by an underscore, i.e., `F[x_]` not `F[_x]`.

Thus

```
f1[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y + 4 + 5*z
f2[x_, y_, z_] = x*y + y^2 + z + 4
f3[x_, y_, z_] = x*y*z

NSolve[{f1[x, y, z] == 0, f2[x, y, z] == 0, f3[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

Only for real roots,

```
NSolve[{f1[x, y, z] == 0, f2[x, y, z] == 0, f3[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 4., y -> 0., z -> -4.}, {x -> -4., y -> 0., z -> -4.}}

Comment: Thanks. Now it's just giving me an empty set, `{}`. To make sure I didn't make up a set of equations with no solution, I switched to a more trivial example, `f1=x+y+z`, `f2=x`, `f3=y`, which should give all zeros, but it still gives `{}`.

Comment: Ok, I missed the `[x,y,z]`s, so it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @sodi, if you think about it: you defined the `f`'s with the brackets around; why would you omit them when you feed them to `NSolve[]`?